# How to solve the error using RANSAC: "RANSAC could not find a valid consensus set. All"

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, ransac

I am using the versions below:

System:

```
    python: 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
executable: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe
   machine: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
```

BLAS:

```
    macros: 
  lib_dirs: 
cblas_libs: cblas
```

Python deps:

```
       pip: 18.1
setuptools: 40.6.3
   sklearn: 0.20.1
     numpy: 1.15.4
     scipy: 1.1.0
    Cython: 0.29.2
    pandas: 0.23.4
```

When I use the RANSAC method I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: RANSAC could not find a valid consensus set. All
>   `max_trials` iterations were skipped because each randomly chosen
>   sub-sample failed the passing criteria. See estimator attributes for
>   diagnostics (n_skips*).

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The default `residual_threshold` RANSAC uses to determine inliers is the median absolute deviation (MAD) of the target variable ([RANSAC docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RANSACRegressor.html)). What may have happened is that the MAD of your target variable is very small, perhaps even zero. In such a case, the algorithm would not be able to find any inliers.

You could try increasing the `residual_threshold` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might have specified boundaries which the model is not able to satisfy. You need to loosen up your pass criteria. This [article](https://medium.com/@angel.manzur/got-outliers-ransac-them-f12b6b5f606e) might help you to figure out better what's going on: